# dot product between two branches of a cnn in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, backpropagation, dot-product

I'm trying to use tensorflow to implement a cnn that, when given two images, it can find in which position both images are the most similar. Something to whats described in here: [Efficient Deep Learning for Stereo Matching](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~urtasun/publications/luo_etal_cvpr16.pdf)

I'm sharing the variables of both branches of the cnn and after that I want to do a dot product of the activations of the left image with all the available positions in the image of the right. 
My question is: if I do this process manually (in a for loop, for example), can tensorflow still backpropagate the gradients through the filters? I'm getting a very unstable and weird loss values and I'm not sure if i'm doing something wrong.

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT:
Here is some code how i initialize the cnn and how I calculate the dot product. I'm not posting the conv layer initialization code for simplicity. I think the problem is in the dot_product function anyway.

```
def init_new_cnn(x_left,x_right,y,nclasses,receptive_field=1,batch_norm=True,padding="VALID"):
    shape=[3,3,3,64]
    conv1_left=cnn.conv_layer_init("conv1",x_left,shape,batch_norm=batch_norm,padding=padding,w_init="xavier")
    shape=[3,3,64,64]
    conv2_left=cnn.conv_layer_init("conv2",conv1_left,shape,batch_norm=batch_norm,padding=padding,w_init="xavier")
    conv3_left=cnn.conv_layer_init("conv3",conv2_left,shape,batch_norm=batch_norm,padding=padding,w_init="xavier")
    conv4_left=cnn.conv_layer_init("conv4",conv3_left,shape,activation=False,batch_norm=batch_norm,padding=padding,w_init="xavier")

    conv1_right=cnn.conv_layer_reuse("conv1",x_right,padding=padding,batch_norm=batch_norm)
    conv2_right=cnn.conv_layer_reuse("conv2",conv1_right,padding=padding,batch_norm=batch_norm)
    conv3_right=cnn.conv_layer_reuse("conv3",conv2_right,padding=padding,batch_norm=batch_norm)
    conv4_right=cnn.conv_layer_reuse("conv4",conv3_right,activation=False,batch_norm=batch_norm,padding=padding)
    image_rows=x_left.get_shape()[1]
    left_cols=x_left.get_shape()[2]
    right_cols=x_right.get_shape()[2]
    batch=x_left.get_shape()[0]
    match=cnn.dot_product(conv4_left, conv4_right, receptive_field,batch,image_rows,left_cols,right_cols,nclasses)
    #match=tf.nn.l2_normalize(match, 3)
    loss=cnn.loss("loss", match,y,loss_type="softmax")
    return loss,match


def dot_product(deconv_left, deconv_right, receptive_field,batch,image_rows,left_cols,right_cols,nclasses):
    res=[]

        for j in range(nclasses-1,-1,-1):
            multiply=tf.mul(deconv_left[n,:,:,:],deconv_right[n,:,j:j+receptive_field,:],name="multiply")#
            dotprod=tf.reduce_sum(multiply,name="sumdotprod")
            res.append(dotprod)

    res=tf.pack(res,name='concat')
    reshaped= tf.reshape(res,(int(batch),1,1,int(nclasses)))
    return reshaped
```

EDIT2: I'm also adding the graph:
[image]

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: Sure, I hope this helps